# How do I disable Google App?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-apps, system-apps, disable-app

I'm using Android 6.0 (non-rooted) phone. Holding home button opens up Google App which I never use.

I don't think that I can change the behavior of holding home button at least as non-root user. (If there's any way or work-around then don't forget to tell me!)

So, as I never use Google App and also want to stop opening Google App by means of home button, I want to disable it as it is a system application hence I can't uninstall it.

But when I opened Google App from system settings, I found disable button is disabled:

[image]

So, How do I disable Google App or there is no option except root?

By the way, it is also not being force-stop with the help of `force-stop` button!

Comment: Rooting is a key to gain privileges like reputation is for this site!

Comment: You must be rooted.

Comment: Have you tried `adb shell pm hide com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`?

Comment: @Firelord no. I'm not familiar with `adb`.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Google app, settings, direct search, disable?

Comment: If this is sock app, how it doesn't have uninstall updates button, or you allredy done that?

Comment: If you didn't uninstalled updates than pres on 3-dot button (if there isn't such than holding recents button should have same effect) and than see if disable button becmes usable. Btw, which device you have?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје There is not update installed of Google App. Device:Lenovo A6600+

Comment: @xangua it's grayed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the behavior of holding home button even as non-root user (at least on my LG G Flex 2 with Android version 6.0.1):

Settings - Apps - Configure apps - Default Apps (in Advanced section) - Assist & voice input - here touch the text "Assist app Google app" not the icon on the right edge - here select None.

Comment: Though the answer is not about disabling Google App actually but as it solves my issue, I've accepted. +1 for helping out

Comment: Worked for me (stock Miui10), 2 years after the answer. That is, these steps helped disassociate the Google app from the home button on my phone (center button for me).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally disable the Google App by updating the app then uninstalling the updates from the 3-dots menu in the top right.  This caused Android to present the `Disable` button.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the data of google app then
Go to play store > options> My apps & games.

[image: My 'Apps&games' >]

Go to 'installed'>Google app > uninstall

Now don't do anything it will show to two options 'update' and 'open'
minimize and close play store.

Then head to the settings > storage & USB > internal storage > Go to google app.

Now you should be able to disable it.

Comment: How do you "minimize and close" Play Store? This isn't Windows.

Comment: After uninstall, app(user app) is completely removed from your app list. Then, how can you disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Settings, Apps, Google App, then Modify System Settings, then switched off
Allow modify system settings.  I could then force stop the app, and disable it. The icon even disappeared from the app drawer with a refresh of the launcher.  Android 7.1.1.

Comment: There is no such option in Android 6.0

Comment: I tried Carl's suggestion above on Android 8.1.  It worked.  However, the Google launcher didn't launch.  I had to pull down the menu at top, go to settings, apps, and enable Google Play Store.  The Google App was enabled again also.    Maybe with another launcher it would have worked.  (On the 7.1.1 I had another launcher, Apex).